# How to add mysqlclient to a Poetry environment

Tags: python, mysql, docker, mysql-python, python-poetry

I'm creating a project which needs to make a connection from Python running in a docker container to a MySQL database running in another container. Currently, my `docker-compose` file looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:

  login:
    build:
      context: ./services/login
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    # Need to remove this volume - this is only for dev work
    volumes:
      - ./services/login/app:/app
    # Need to remove this command - this is only for dev work
    command: /start-reload.sh

  db_users:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql/users_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./databases/users:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    # Remove 'expose' below for prod
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: users
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

And my `Dockerfile` for the `login` service looks like this:

```
# Note: this needs to be run from parent service directory

FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8

# Install Poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry python && \
    cd /usr/local/bin && \
    ln -s /opt/poetry/bin/poetry && \
    poetry config virtualenvs.create false

# Copy using poetry.lock* in case it doesn't exist yet
COPY ./app/pyproject.toml ./app/poetry.lock* /app/

RUN poetry install --no-root --no-dev

COPY ./app /app
```

I am trying to connect my `login` service to `db_users`, and want to make use of [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/), but when I run `poetry add mysqlclient`, I get an error which includes the following lines:

```
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/33/5yy7bny964bb0f3zggd1b4440000gn/T/pip-req-build-lak6lqu7/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/33/5yy7bny964bb0f3zggd1b4440000gn/T/pip-req-build-lak6lqu7/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/private/var/folders/33/5yy7bny964bb0f3zggd1b4440000gn/T/pip-req-build-lak6lqu7/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    mysql_config --version
    mariadb_config --version
    mysql_config --libs
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm assuming this is something to do with the fact that I need the mysql-connector-c library to work, but I'm not sure how to go about getting this in poetry.

I was looking at following [this](https://ruddra.com/install-mysqlclient-macos/) tutorial, but since I'm not running MySQL locally but rather in docker, I'm not sure how to translate those steps to work in docker.

So essentially, my question is two-fold:

1. How do I add `mysqlclient` to my `pyproject.toml` file
2. How do I get this working in my docker env?

Comment: You need to figure out how to install the missing mysql dependencies. It depends on the base of the docker image. For example if it's based on ubuntu/debian then you might need to issue some `apt install` commands.

Comment: Hi @sinoroc, so that makes sense for the docker side of things but I also need to add this to my `pyproject.toml` file and `poetry add mysqlclient` is failing with the above error

Comment: You can't solve the `poetry add mysqlclient` part until you fix the other part first. This `mysqlclient` Python project has mandatory dependencies that can not be installed via _poetry_ and/or _pip_. This has to be solved beforehand. Read the doc: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

I understand my docker image will need those steps, but then even after that how would I declare in my `pyproject.toml` file that there is a dependency on `mysqlclient`? I've been doing this normally with `poetry add [package]`

Comment: If you call `poetry add Something`, then that `Something` is ***1.*** added to the `pyproject.toml` and ***2.*** installed in the (virtual) environment (and probably ***3.*** added to `poetry.lock` as well) it is a bit more complicated than that and happens likely in a different order, but it does not matter. Alternatively you can also add `Something` to `pyproject.toml` yourself by hand and then call `poetry install`.

Comment: Ahh right, I see, that makes sense. And since I don't really need the poetry virtual env since I'm working in docker, it doesn't matter if its installed there or not so I don't need to do `poetry add ...` 

Thanks for your help sinoroc! Seemingly got that working through the dockerfile now, will know properly once I've started to play with it and connect with mysql but should be good for now :)

Comment: You still need to do something like `poetry add mysqlclient` or `python -m pip install mysqlclient` to install this library. Of course. Otherwise it is not installed. It is just that the Python library `mysqlclient` depends on other Mysql-related libraries that are not pip-installable and that should be installed through different ways (with `apt` on Debian/Ubuntu for example). So yes, you most likely need to install both of those things: the Python part and the non-Python part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forgetting that my dev environment is also in Docker so I didn't really need to care about the poetry environment.

With that said, I edited the Dockerfile to look like the below:

```
# Note: this needs to be run from parent service directory

FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8

RUN apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev

# Install Poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry python && \
    cd /usr/local/bin && \
    ln -s /opt/poetry/bin/poetry && \
    poetry config virtualenvs.create false

# Copy using poetry.lock* in case it doesn't exist yet
COPY ./app/pyproject.toml ./app/poetry.lock* /app/

RUN poetry install --no-root --no-dev

COPY ./app /app
```

Which now has everything working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

For all other people who are led here by google because they can't add mysqlclient to poetry:

The issue is that mysqlclient is not the name of the python package that you are looking for. You need to run the following:

```
poetry add mysql-connector-python
```